# Populating form data from server using axios request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, axios

So I am trying to populate a form with data from my server. The server is returning just fine. All strings. I want each form field to be populated with the current details from the database.

I tried the following:

- setting each state function in useEffect, but this wouldn't allow me
  to change form data
- setting a default value but this only works for one instance of the
  form and then changes back

  ```
  function Dashboard(props) {
      const { classes } = props;

      let user = firebase.getCurrentUser(); 
      let id = user.uid;

      const [profile, setProfileData] = useState(''); 

      useEffect( () => {
          axios.get('https://www.memento-wedding.com/user/' + id)
          .then(response => {
              setProfileData(response.data); 
          }) 
          console.log(profile.gender);
      }); 

      const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
      const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
      const [date, setDate] = useState('');
      const [gender, setGender] = useState();

      return (
          <div className="form">
          <h1 className="white center">Welcome, {firebase.getCurrentUsername()}!</h1> 
          <h1 className="white center">Create a Profile</h1>
          <Form onSubmit={e => e.preventDefault() && false}>
              <Row form>
              <Label for="firstName" sm={3} className="white right">First Name</Label>
              <Col sm={6}>
                  <Input type="text" name="firstName" id="name" value={firstName} onChange={e=>setFirstName(e.target.value)}/>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={1}></Col>
              </Row>
              <br></br>
              <Row form>
              <Label for="firstName" sm={3} className="white right">Last Name</Label>
              <Col sm={6}>
                  <Input type="text" name="firstName" id="name" value={lastName} onChange={e=>setLastName(e.target.value)}/>
              </Col>
              <Col sm={1}></Col>
              </Row>
              <br></br>
              <Row form>
              <Label for="email" sm={3} className="white right">Email</Label>
              <Col sm={6}>
                  <Input type="email" name="email" id="email" disabled value={profile.email}/>
              </Col>
              </Row>
              <br></br>
              <Row form>
              <Label for="birthday" sm={3} className="white right">Birthday</Label>
              <Col sm={6}>
                  <Input type="date" name="date" id="date" value={date} onChange={e=>setDate(e.target.value)}/>
              </Col>
              </Row>
              <br></br>  
              <Row>
              <Label for="gender" sm={3} className="white right">Gender</Label>
              <Col md={5} sm={7}>
              <RadioButtons gender={gender} setGender={e=>setGender(e.target.value)} />
              </Col>
              </Row>
           </Form>
      )
  ```

  }

Answer (score 0):

Please add filter condition []

```
useEffect( () => {
    axios.get('https://www.memento-wedding.com/user/' + id)
    .then(response => {
        setProfileData(response.data); 
    }) 
    console.log(profile.gender);
},[]);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: If you do not add a empty [] condition your component will go into recursion

Comment: As useEffect is basically componentDidMount + componentDidUpdate